# Transform Large XML file using VB6 and XSLT

Tags: xml, vb6, xslt-1.0

I have a large XML file about 300mb and when i try to transform it with XSLT, it always ends up having out of memory error, can anyone recommend a good solution for me to be able to transform the XML file successfully without that error.

I am using VB6 and transforming the XML with  XSLT 1.0 and im using DOMDocument to load the XML document.

Comment: MSXML IXSLProcessor must accept input from a DOM but its output can be sent through a SAX Writer.  That eliminates the memory penalty of an output DOM, which might or might not be enough.

Comment: If possible discard XSLT entirely and write a custom program to transform using SAX input and output.  XSLT was designed for lightweight use in limited scripting environments.

Answer (score 1):

You're using some pretty ancient technology here, and it's not clear from your question whether you are constrained by that environment for ever.

300Mb is doable using a modern XSLT processor such as Saxon, it will probably need 2Gb of memory. Many XSLT processors have an internal tree model that is much more space-efficient than DOM, but I don't know where you stand with MSXML.

We don't know anything about the transformation you are doing and whether it is amenable to streaming (that is, processing without building the entire tree model in memory). If it is potentially streamable then there's a variety of approaches you could consider (including XSLT 3.0) but your options in VB6 are likely to be quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

As Bob77 pointed out, you should definitively switch to `SAXXMLReader` and rewrite your `XSLT` transformations using this lightweight technology.

Create a class module and include the statement `Implements IVBSAXContentHandler`.

Use the events `IVBSAXContentHandler_startElement` and `IVBSAXContentHandler_endElement` to do *on the fly*  the needed changes, as the file is being parsed as it is read.

You may find enough examples of a ready-to use SAX class on MSDN.